# What is the best way to test HTTPPOST request by passing model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, http-post

I am using Castle Windsor as DI and using reposity to access and implement the data layers. 
As I have implemented all the data access layer in my repo, it is time to call those methods in my API controller. SO I have 'getAllReportsByClient method' and 'CreateReport' POST method. So, in order to test if some methods are working without actually implementing the view and AJAX call, how can I insert sample data using my 'Create Report' method?

The method from repo is below:

```
public void CreateReport(TReportHeaderModel model)

        {

            using (var connection = new TReportEntitiesConnection())
            {

                connection.THeader.Add(new THeader()
                {

                    ClientID=model.ClientID,
                    ID=model.ID,
                    THeaderTitle=model.THeaderTitle,
                    RowNumber=model.RowNumber

                });


                foreach (var d in model.TReports)
                {
                    connection.TReport.Add(new TReport()
                    {

                        ID=d.ID,
                        TReportName=d.TReportName,
                        URL=d.URL,
                        RowNumber=d.RowNumber,



                    });

                }

                connection.SaveChanges();


            }



                throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
```

The below is HTTPPOST createReport call in Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResultModel CreateReport([FromBody] TReportHeaderModel model) 

    {


        try
        {
            _tReportingService.CreateReport(model);

            return new ActionResultModel()   //return void, must not be followed by object expression
            {
                Success = true,
                Message = "Report Successfully Created."
            };

        }


        catch (Exception ex)

        {
            return new ActionResultModel()
            {
                Success = false,
                Message = "Report not created.",
                Obj=ex.Message

            };


        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Postman(https://www.getpostman.com/) or Fiddler(www.telerik.com/fiddler) to emulate the request. Even better, you could write a test using a testing framework.